# How to extract information from stdClass object?

Tags: laravel, stdclass

In the `build` function of my Mailable I extract information from a database like so:

```
$this->data = DB::select('select * from newsletter_mails order by id desc limit 1')[0];

\Log::info(print_r($this->data, true));

$this->subject = $this->data->subject;
$this->content = $this->data->content;

\Log::info(print_r($this->subject, true));
\Log::info(print_r($this->content, true));
```

which yields the log:

```
[2021-11-13 15:49:41] production.INFO: stdClass Object
(
    [id] => 2
    [from] => test@test.com
    [subject] => testSubject
    [content] => testMessage
    [file] => 
    [created_at] => 2021-11-13 15:49:10
    [updated_at] => 2021-11-13 15:49:10
)
  
[2021-11-13 15:49:41] production.INFO: testSubject  
[2021-11-13 15:49:41] production.INFO: testMessage
```

As you can see `data` variable is a `stdClass Object` and the information gets extracted correctly. But now I want to get the `from` value:

```
$this->from = $this->data->from;

\Log::info(print_r($this->from, true));
```

This outputs two things in the log. First the correct output for `$this->form`:

```
[2021-11-13 15:55:25] production.INFO: test@test.com
```

But also an error:

```
[2021-11-13 15:55:25] production.ERROR: Cannot access offset of type string on string {"userId":1,"exception":"[object] (TypeError(code: 0): Cannot access offset of type string on string at C:\\Users\\Artur\\PhpstormProjects\\stuttard.de\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Mail\\Mailable.php:360)
[stacktrace]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why are you using RAW sql ??? The point of using Laravel (among others) it to use [Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent)... Read the [entire documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x) so you know what you can do and how should you do something with the framework...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You store the data in $this->data property and also overriding all other properties of the Mailable class.

You should store the data from the database in a local variable like this:

```
$data = DB::select('select * from newsletter_mails order by id desc limit 1')[0];
$from = $data->from;

\Log::info(print_r($from, true));
```

Comment: Whelp, that solved it. Will keep this in mind for the future. Thank you

Comment: Good that it worked for you :)